# Managing startup, how to control stress levels?

Tags: professionalism, management, united-kingdom, startup, stress

I work in small startup company, during the sprints we have very stressful atmosphere, caused by short deadlines and underslept personnel. How can I handle or at least mitigate this situation as a manager ?

Comment: Why not do the obvious: more manageable amount of work?

Comment: Have you considered using something *other* than 2-week Scrum-style sprints? I know of organizations finding success with the [Basecamp Shape Up method](https://basecamp.com/shapeup), which works in [six-week cycles](https://basecamp.com/shapeup/0.3-chapter-01#six-week-cycles).

Comment: “We are trying to push platform into this huge world that will hopefully compete with many others” — is that huge world going to disappear if you push your (presumably self-imposed) deadlines back a bit so that people can sleep properly, and do their best work?

Answer (score 109):

There is only one way to mitigate the "under-sleep" problem: allow your employees to have a healthy life, and to separate the job life from the private life.

Other than that, you need somebody who understands management to deal with the things. Based on the work needed, they will estimate the resources required: how many people, their required experience, computers, servers, salaries, other benefits...

It seems that employees are overworked by the management, which will lead to only one result: they will leave.

---

In some startups, the employees are engaged and do the overtime because they want. However, in these startups, there is no stress "due to the short deadlines".

If we talk about "short deadlines", then we speak about the desires of an unrealistic manager. Combined with "very stressful atmosphere", the picture is complete. The actual "management team" is a dictatorial and not connected to the reality. To them, people are not people, but just resources - just good for exploitation.

---

> how to control stress levels?

Actually, you cannot directly control the stress levels. Stress is just a result, an outcome. Address all the root causes of the stress (e.g., the short deadlines), and stress will go away by itself.

Comment: +1, this is clearly an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/662798). Attack the causes, not the effects!

Comment: `Actually, you cannot control the stress levels. Stress is just a result, an outcome.` - Results and outcomes are controllable.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: How do you control stress as an outcome directly, without touching the cause? Beat the people until the stress goes away? Drug them? Hypnotize them? You made me very curious.

Comment: @virolino In this particular case, "beatings will continue until stress levels are reduced"

Comment: @Yuropoor: Perfectly stated! :) +1

Comment: I didn't say any of what you're suggesting. Your statements amount to "You can't control outcomes." This is not true. If you focus your efforts on fixing the things that stress your people, you absolutely can control that outcome. Perhaps your point would be more accurately said as "You can't control stress levels without addressing its root cause."

Comment: @JoelEtherton Isn't that exactly what the answerer wrote? "Actually, you cannot control the stress levels. Stress is just a result, an outcome. **Address all the root causes of the stress (e.g., the short deadlines), and stress will go away by itself.**" (emphasis added). It's very unclear what you're disagreeing with.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Form my point of view, "control the cause" and "control the result" are very different topics. Additionally, the tone of your message (as well as the letter) was that you contradict my answer, which only completes the picture. Otherwise, your comment would be pointless, the way I read it.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: In the answer, I added "directly" to clarify the way of controlling the stress, for your convenience.

Comment: @JonBentley: I'm disagreeing with the statement that indicates you can't control an outcome. You absolutely can control an outcome. Stress doesn't "go away by itself". You address the root, that affects (i.e. controls) the outcome. Saying one correct thing in a paragraph of incorrect things doesn't fix what is being said.

Comment: @virolino: That hasn't changed it. By addressing the causes of stress you are directly controlling those levels. If I pour water directly into a glass, I'm controlling how full of liquid it is. This paragraph needs to be fixed to indicate that you CAN control the outcome and the stress levels (because you can) and that stress doesn't go away by itself. Stress goes away by management removing or reducing stressors.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Please ask a question about controlling the cause / effect and I will be happy to answer. The answer is too long to fit here. Also, removing a child with stones will NOT make a window not broken - which is the conclusion of your last statement. If you stop saying bad words to somebody, that other person will not suddenly forget the anger and love you unconditionally again. You seem to have a very limited understanding of reality, unfortunately. Mathematically, cause and effect are not linked by a bijective function. Also, a cause can have many effects, and an effect many causes.

Comment: @virolino: Please don't make accusations in a discussion. I haven't said anything negative about you in the least. I have criticized an answer I disagree with. To use your broken window analogy, you will have to replace the window. And when you stop the child from throwing stones, you will have affected its propensity to be broken again. I think you're feeling in your analogy is that the stone through the window is the cause. The child throwing the stones is the cause. The stone through the window is a state. Replacing the window changes its state. Stopping the child affects future outcomes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113291/discussion-between-joel-etherton-and-virolino).

Comment: "There is only one way to mitigate the "under-sleep" problem: allow your employees to have a healthy life, and to separate the job life from the private life." I can think of another way: drugs. A popular, legal one is caffeine, but some militaries have used amphetamines.

Comment: @nick012000: maybe you should make an explicit note that you are being jocular / sarcastic, otherwise some "managers" will actually put it into practice, quoting you :D To reuse Yuropoor's joke, "physically beating the sleep out of them" might also be a solution - even cheaper maybe.

Comment: @virolino No, I'm being entirely serious. Heck, I wouldn't be surprised if there weren't exploitative companies already doing this, in e.g. the gaming industry.

Comment: Reality beats any science, we know that. But regarding the overall benefits, an image is better than 1000 words. Just search for "the effect of drugs on spiders" - and you will see that cofefe is not at all that harmless and beneficial as it is promoted to be.

Comment: You can fight stress without fighting the causes - if you teach the employees not to care about mad deadlines and unrealistic demands. I'm old enough now that you can tell me "there's a two weeks deadline for this task which will take four weeks and you'll have to work 60 hours a week" and I won't stress - but the task will be finished in four weeks, and I won't work more than 40 hours a week and I don't care how much stress that causes the manager.

Comment: @gnasher729: your comment does not make sense to me. I do not understand what you want to say. I only get the hint that you refer to "manage the effects of the stress" as "manage the stress" - and they are different.

Answer (score 24):

> I work in small startup company, during the sprints we have very
> stressful atmosphere, caused by short deadlines and underslept
> personnel. How can I handle or at least mitigate this situation as a
> manager ?

You need to either better manage expectations of stakeholders, and thus reduce the workload that goes onto the team (by removing features, cutting corners, buying read-made solutions, ways to do that are endless and are a compromise), or you need to better explain the problem of not enough manpower to the stakeholders and get a budget for more people.

Otherwise if you will continue on the path you are now, where you are overpromising to the stakeholders and then pushing the team to the breaking point then the team will eventually burn out and leave, sometimes in the ambulance if it's as bad as you describe it.

Comment: Even though correct, the answer is dangerously over-simplified. It is quite obvious that the current management team does not have the skills / experience to actually do management. They seem to be more like "YES-sayers" to the clients and "order-givers" to the development team, while being titled "managers". When management is missing, adding more people to the team is actually counterproductive and an additional source of stress.

Comment: @virolino you are guessing that's the case though. And while it's a likely correct guess, unless op provides more details of how exactly their process works, that's as detailed as I can get without making some far-reaching assumptions.

Comment: I agree, a clear solution cannot be proposed based on the info in the question.

Comment: @virolino: "They seem to be more like "YES-sayers" to the clients and "order-givers" to the development team, while being titled "managers"". Excellent, concise description.

Comment: I often say that the job of a manager is "tanking" for the team, to use a gaming term. The managers hold back the expectations of the stakeholders and customers, buying more time and room for the team to get the job done.

Answer (score 24):

Do not allow people to work for more than 40 hours a week.

[Various studies](https://www.inc.com/tom-popomaronis/science-says-you-shouldnt-work-more-than-this-number-of-hours-a-day.html) have shown that people simply can not work efficiently for more than 40 hours a week over longer stretches of time. Overstraining this stress level results in lack of concentration which reduces the work output and increases the amount of mistakes made. The result is that the weekly output of a worker *decreases* when you have them work more than 40 hours.

It might sound counter-intuitive, but your company might be able to accomplish more by working less.

Being a startup has nothing to do with this. "Startup culture" does not mean overworking people until they burn out. This does not work in "corporate" and it does not work in startups either. If you can not accomplish your objectives with a regular work week, then that's a planning problem:

- Negotiate realistic deadlines
- Learn to say No to unrealistic stakeholder demands
- Work smarter, not harder:

  - Optimize your internal processes to minimize time spent on bureaucracy or unproductive meetings. Identify and remove bottlenecks in your processes.
  - Prioritize tasks which give you the most benefit for the least amount of work
  - Make sure everyone has access to all the resources, tools and equipment they need to work as efficiently as possible.

Comment: And for all of these, they need to hire a real manager. The current management team is totally away from the subject. While they can still start learning what management really is, the time goes by and the project will fail.

Comment: First study I heard of was by Eysenck, mid 1940's, where he found that in arms production in the UK during WWII (so you shouldn't be able to find anyone more motivated to perform), people working 57 hours per week did _less work_ than people working 48 hours a week. You very quickly reach the point where not only you destroy your employees' lives, but you do it for no gain whatsoever.

Answer (score -3):

#### Provide them with drugs.

Both sleep deprivation and high levels of stress are problems that can be solved (or at least mitigated) with drugs. Stimulants can be used to ward off the negative effects of sleep deprivation; a popular, legal one is caffeine; military organizations have occasionally used amphetamines to allow them to support a high operational tempo, but that isn't an option for any civilian organizations due to anti-drug laws. There are a wide variety of [psychiatric medications](https://www.mentalhelp.net/stress/reduction/medication/) that can reduce stress; however, many of them are potentially addictive, and aside from some herbal medications, they all require prescriptions from a doctor. You might also consider experimenting with providing them with [nootropic "smart drug" supplements](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/features/nootropics-smart-drugs-overview) as a further performance improvement measure (and several of these are already combined with caffeine in energy drinks).

Obviously, this is a "solution" that won't address the root causes of these issues, and the company would be liable for any negative outcomes that the drugs might cause; consulting a doctor about potential interactions between the contents of any drug cocktails you're providing to your employees would probably be a wise decision to make, from a corporate liability standpoint. Consulting an employment lawyer about corporate liability for damage to the health of your employees would probably be wise, regardless.

However, you may be able to spin this in a positive way to improve morale, by positioning yourself as a trendy, supportive employer providing your employees a perk: "We're providing you with free energy drinks, coffee, chamomile tea, and anti-stress herbal supplements to help support your passion as we work together to deliver our products."

Comment: I... what? This reads as a funny answer to a serious problem, and while I appreciate the humor, this cannot be taken as a serious advice (unless OP workplace is a labor camp in some god forgotten place). Disregarding any type of medication (which is for actual health problems, not to drug oneself), this reads to me as "I know you must complete this 2 month project in 1 week, and you work 18 hours a day, but hey, here's your coffee, now you have no problem".

Comment: I honestly hope this is a troll/comedy comment because otherwise it's possibly the worst advice I've seen in a long time.

Comment: @RichCampbell No, totally serious. I half expect that there's already companies doing this. That's why I suggested that the consult a doctor to make sure there's no drug interactions between anything they offer their employees - and that they should probably consult a lawyer regarding liability regarding the damage they're already doing to their employees' health.

Comment: Caffeine and sugar are also addictive.  Your employers will keep coming back for their "fix".  People are criticizing this answer but what company does not provide free coffee (and why do they provide free coffee?).  However, this answer is probably not useful to OP because OP's company is probably already providing as many drugs as they can get away with.

Comment: @RichCampbell I don't think most people have heard about nootropics and how they can be better than just plain coffee/caffeine. This post mentions historical uses of using substances and warns about their dangers. Moreover it provides an improvement that doesn't need a company reorganisation. It's answering OP's question professionally. Saying it's a joke is not a good way to ask for improvement.

Comment: @emory many employers provide decaf and artificial sweeteners, as well. They think of them as an investment in comfort, which makes stressed workers more productive. Also, stimulants and anxiolytics are no mitigators for sleep deprivation: they might increase alertness, but at the cost of creativity and rational skills. They're useful in wars, when most people are just pawns in a battlefield, [but they backfire when you need to assign diverse tasks to a heterogeneous team](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/08/08/the-command-and-control-management-method/).

Comment: @RamonMelo Everyone would like to believe they are valued for their creativity and rational skills but many people are just pawns in a battlefield.  There is a lot of short-term thinking and many common tactics backfire.

Comment: @emori having faith in being valued for their creativity and rational skills makes employees more productive in itself. Office workers like feeling valued, even if it's just an illusion. I'm afraid providing performance drugs to a team already feeling unmotivated won't make it feel valued. Don't get me wrong: I'm all for brain-hacking, but, coming from the employers, it would likely rub it off the wrong way.